# Finding the parallel transport of $S^2$ with constant zenith angle

Tags: differential-geometry

In *Elementary Topics of Differential Geometry*, page 49, Thorpe states, in an example:

> For $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\alpha_\theta: [0, \pi] \rightarrow S^2$ be the parameterized curve, in the unit 2-sphere, from the north pole, $p = (0, 0, 1)$ to the south pole $q = (0, 0, -1)$, defined by $$\alpha_\theta(t) = (\cos{\theta}\sin{t}, \sin{\theta}\sin{t}, \cos{t}).$$
>   Thus, for each $\theta$, $\alpha_\theta$ is half of a great circle on $S^2$. Let $v = (p,1,0,0) \in S^2_p$. Since $\alpha_\theta$ is a geodesic in $S^2$, a vector field tangent to $S^2$ along $\alpha_\theta$ will be parallel if and only if it has constant length and keeps constant angle with $\dot{\alpha_\theta}$. The one with initial value $v$ is $$V_\theta(t) = (\cos{\theta})\dot{\alpha_\theta}(t) - (\sin{\theta})N(\alpha_\theta(t)) \times \dot{\alpha_\theta}(t)$$ where $N$ is the outward orientation on $S^2$.

... Where does he get $V_\theta(t)$? There's a huge leap (at least to the untrained eye) between the statement of the requirements and the conclusion that $V_\theta(t)$ must be what it is. I know the requirements must be satisfied, I just don't know how he went from that to (seemingly, magically) getting $V_\theta(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that it must have constant length and keep constant angle with $\dot{\alpha}_\theta$. Its angle with $\dot{\alpha}_\theta$ is $\theta$.

Now think of a moving frame along the geodesic $\alpha_\theta$ with the first coordinate in each tangent space the span of $\dot{\alpha}_\theta$ and the second coordinate its positively oriented perpendicular. This is constructed by $-N(\alpha_\theta(t))\times\dot{\alpha}_\theta$. (The minus sign comes from the orientation.)

Now remember that $|\nu| = 1$. What unit vector has angle $\theta$ with $\dot{\alpha}_\theta$? In coordinates, $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. The basis is $(\dot{\alpha}_\theta,-N(\alpha_\theta)\times\dot{\alpha}_\theta)$, so the parallel transport of $\nu$ along $\alpha$ is what he says it is.